# Перевод в разделе "Запоздалые ответы" при нажатии на тревогу

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок

Если поставить флаг тревоги до этого и словить на проверку это же сообщение, то во всплывающем окне часть фраз не переведена:

- You already have a pending flag on this answer
- This is the flag you currently have raised
- Retract flag

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Поправил. В ближайшее время строки будут доступны на сайте.